# How to remove columns if the value of one specific row is 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a fairly straight forward question but I could not find the answer on stack.
I have a pd.df

```
Index   A  B  C
0       1  1  0
1       0  0  0 
2       1  1  1
3       0  0  1
```

I simply wish to remove all columns where the fourth row (3) is 0. So only column `C` would remain. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "Index" the index, you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df.loc[:, df.iloc[3].ne(0)]
```

output:

```
   C
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  1
```

output of `df.iloc[3].ne(0)`:

```
A    False
B    False
C     True
Name: 3, dtype: bool
```